# Ruby Gem versions incompatible with version of ruby

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I have recently installed a system running ubuntu 12.04 LTS as part of a cluster of similar machines running the same software.

I have struck and issue with sys-proctable which when installed by default fails to load with the error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sys-proctable-0.9.9-universal-linux/lib/linux/sys/proctable.rb:2:
undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Require_relative is a ruby 1.9 feature and ubuntu 12.04 installs 1.87.

I tried uninstalling the sys-proctable gem and installing the -0.9.4 version which is what I have on the other systems but I get

```
rful011@secmonprd07:~$ sudo gem -v 0.9.4 install sys-proctable
[sudo] password for rful011:
1.8.15
```

and nothing else.

I don't have much flexibility in changing ruby version or OS versions as this machine is part of a much bigger setup.

Any ideas why the attempt to install a specific version prints what appears to be a vesion number and then exits?

Any suggestions for minimalist work arounds.

Comment: I have found a work around but i am still interested as to why I could not install a different version of the gem.

Work around was to uninstall ruby1.8 and install 1.9.  I am not sure if this work around is viable as other parts of the system are 'officially' dependent on 1.8.  I suspect that this is a minimum dependency and things appear to work.

Fingers crossed

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 is so horribly out of date it isn't funny. Please, please upgrade ASAP.

Comment: @sevenseacat: Not only is Ruby 1.8.7 [end-of-lifed](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/07/01/eol-for-1-8-7-and-1-9-2/), Ubuntu 12.04 is as well.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is LTS and supported till mid 2017.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to install a specific version of a gem is

```
$ gem install the_gem -v 1.2.3
```

i.e. in your case, with `sudo`, you should use:

```
$ sudo gem install sys-proctable -v 0.9.4
```

The command you have used is:

```
gem -v 0.9.4 install sys-proctable
```

i.e. you have the `-v 0.9.4` *before* the `install` subcommand. In this case the `gem` executable interprets the `-v` as the version switch (this can also be specified with `--version`), which causes it to print out the version of Rubygems. Anything after the `-v` is ignored.

So there are *two* types of `-v` (or `--version`) flag. The first is written directly after `gem` (it is the first argument to the command) and causes it to print its version and exit, ignoring anything else on the command line. The second is placed after the gem name when using the `install` subcommand and specifies the version of the gem you want to be installed. You have just got the wrong one.

See `gem help` and `gem help install` for more details.

Comment: Doh! and Thanks! It had to be simple.  I read the gem help, but not carefully enough.